# Why can't I push this additional data into my array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm making an API call and here is the response

[image]

As you can see, key 0 & 1 have NULL for their 'outcome_status' whereas key 2 is populated. **The number of returned results is dynamic**

I wish to loop the results and push the 'category' & 'location' details into the array and if 'outcome_status' isn't NULL then I wish to add that data into the same array.

The problem is, within the IF statement that checks if outcome_status is null, I can't assign the forloop `var i;` variable as the key for 
 mapData where I use`.push()` the second time.

> line:68 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

```
var mapData = [];
function getPolApi(year,month,lat,lng,mapData) {
    $.ajax({
    url : "https://data.police.uk/api/crimes-at-location?date="+year+"-"+month+"&lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng,
    type : "get",
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      mapData = [];// Empty the array of old results
      for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
```

**EDIT: I want to do this.**

```
            mapData.push([
              data[i]['category'],
              data[i]['location']['street']['name'],
              data[i]['outcome_status']['category'],
              data[i]['outcome_status']['date']
            ]);
```

**But if there is no `outcome_status` then it will fail... So I added the second part into a conditional instead**

```
         if(data[i].outcome_status != null) { 

          //In order to access the original array by key,
         // I wish to the use the forloop iteration otherwise 
         //mapData.push() will add the data as NEW arrays instead of adding on to the end of the existing arrays.

          //Why can't I use the current index for the key here?

              mapData[i].push([ //line 68

              data[i]['outcome_status']['category'],
              data[i]['outcome_status']['date'],
            ]);
         }
           heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].location.latitude,data[i].location.longitude));
      }

      console.log(mapData);
       //Add results into view

          for(var i = 0; i < mapData.length; i++) {
             var fill = '<div class="row resu"><div class="col-xs-2 number"><h5>'+[i+1]+'</h5></div><div class="col-xs-10"><p class="text-primary">Type of crime: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][0]+'</span></p><p class="text-primary">Location specifics: <span class="text-strong">'+mapData[i][1]+'</span></p></div></div>';
            $('.output').append(fill);

          }//endforloop

          //Move the map into view of the heatmaps
          moveMap(lat,lng);
          //Add the heatmaps
          addHeatMap();

      // console.log(mapData);
    },
    error: function(dat) {
       console.log('error');
    }
 });
```

Comment: `mapData[i]` is the object in question.  What are you trying to accomplish with your push?

Comment: shouldnt this `if(!data[i].outcome_status == null)` be this `if(data[i].outcome_status !== null)`

Comment: If your `for` initializes `i` as `1`, and you call `mapData.push()` *once*, then in the first iteration, `mapData[]` only has **one** item when it gets to `mapData[i].push(...)` . It's trying to call `.push()` on `mapData[1]` when `mapData[]` only has one item.

Comment: @JaimeTorres mapData[i] would actually mean mapData[0], mapData[1] inside the forloop... I'm trying to use the `i` so that I can add the data back into the same array that I set above.

Comment: @ProEvilz but the `for` loop starts at **1**, not 0.

Comment: if I remove the [i] on mapData then new arrays are inserted instead of the data being added to the existing array

Comment: See my edits....

Comment: Change the for loop to start at 0, and it will work

Comment: Add that as your answer Jaime

Comment: @ProEvilz I commented that 13 minutes ago and posted it as an answer 4 minutes ago. Just a bit curious as to why are you asking someone else to post it...?

Comment: blame SO loading of answers and comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- Your `for` loop starts with *i* equal to one, so even after the first push, `mapData[i]` does not yet exist, so applying `push` to that makes no sense.
- If you want to `push` additional elements to an existing array, you should not add those additional elements as part of an array, but provide them as separate arguments to `push`.

Furthermore, the code becomes a bit more functional when use array methods like `map`.

Here is how the part to fill `mapData` and `heatmapData` could look like:

```
// Create a new array, with nested arrays: one per data item
mapData = data.map(function (item) {
    // Use a local variable to build the sub-array:
    var arr = [
      item.category,
      item.location.street.name,
    ];
    if (item.outcome_status) { // add 2 more elements if they exist
        arr.push( // note: no square brackets here
            item.outcome_status.category,
            item.outcome_status.date,
        );
    }
    // Add it to `dataMap` by returning it to the `map` callback:
    return arr;
});

// Extend the heatmap with additional locations
heatmapData = heatmapData.concat(data.map(function (item) {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(item.location.latitude,item.location.longitude);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Issue:

Here, you initialize `i` as 1:

```
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
```

---

You then push one item to `mapData[]`:

```
mapData.push([
    data[i]['category'],
    data[i]['location']['street']['name'],
]);
```

---

A couple lines later, you try to access `mapData[i]`...

```
mapData[i].push([
    data[i]['outcome_status']['category'],
    data[i]['outcome_status']['date'],
]);
```

This is trying to access `mapData[1]`, but `mapData[]` only has one item at this point. You need `mapData[0]`.

---

### The Solution:

Try simply changing your `i` to initialize as `0` instead of `1`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

If this is not sufficient and `data[]` needs to be a 1-index, then perhaps `mapData[i-1]` instead of `mapData[i]` would suit your needs.